# How to get intellisense with own javascript files in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I'm utilizing vscode `Version 1.14.2 (1.14.2)` and I'm trying to get intellisense for my own javascript files. To test this I created two files `test.js` and `main.js`. In the `test.js` I have the following code...

```
{
  Test = {};

  let testObj = {};

  Test.getAllTest = function() {
    return testObj;
  };
}
```

In my `main.js` file I have the following...

```
/// <reference path="./test.js" />
{
  Test.
}
```

I'm wanting to have intellisense about my own code. Is it possible to accomplish this in vscode?

### Update August 10, 2017

The previous code it's a silly snippet as you can notice. Let me paste code from an exercise I'm working on...

```
"use strict";

var $ = require("../lib/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js");

let line = console.log;
let bakery = {};

bakery.loadInventory = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://cake-2444b.firebaseio.com/ccakes.json"
    })
      .done(function(data) {
        resolve(data);
      })
      .fail(function(error) {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = bakery;
```

jQuery is installed with `--save-dev` and I suspect that I can't `require('jQuery')` for that very reason. The previous code is living in a file called `bakery-factory.js`. Bellow, I'm including a screenshot showing that the intellinsense is not working for the module.

[image]

I want to add that I'm utilizing Grunt to run few tasks. I'm not sure if that has something to do with the intellisense issue. I'm very happy with the editor and I would like to get this to work.

### Update August 11, 2017

I got it working by following your advice of...

```
let bakery = {
    loadInventory: function(...
```

The way I had it before doesn't work...

```
let bakery = {}

bakery.loadInventory = function(...
```

Thank you for explaining!!

Answer (score 0):

VSCode 1.15 can only provide limited intellisense in this case. There are two problems:

- We don't support implicit global assignments, like `Test = ...`. You need to declare the variable `var Test = ...` and then create a simple [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson) file so that all JS files in your workspace share the same global context.
- Our intellisense also doesn't recognized properties that are added to an object after it is created. This is a bug and tracked by: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10868 Instead, you'd need to declare the namespace member at time of assignment: `var Test = { getAllTest: ... }`

If possible, I recommend you look into using proper modules with well defined imports and exports. These will provide a much better IntelliSense experience and, more importantly, make the code far more maintainable and easier to reason about.